# Android, Two applications active at the same time

Tags: android, multi-window

Is it possible to display one application(rendering Video) as a floating screen in one half of the screen. and at the same time interacting with another application(e.g chat application or any other application. ).
Basically the rendering Video application should be on top which should keep displaying the video while the user can interact with the background application, i.e the chat application.
I had a look at the FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL

flag but will the rendering of the video go on unhampered.

Comment: have you considered using fragments, a fragment for video rendering and another fragment for chatting.. or are you pointing that you have a completely separated applications for each. then I don't think it is possible

Comment: No, only the video rendering application will be my application. the other one can be anything. chat application is just an example.